# Open XML Power Tools Identifying Paragraph Indexes

Tags: c#, openxml

I’m having an issue merging complex documents with headers at specific locations.

Here’s an example:

```
var letterhead = @"C:\Users\dheale\Desktop\Word Docs\TESTING\StandardLetterhead.DOCX";
var blackrule = @"C:\Users\dheale\Desktop\Word Docs\TESTING\NJBlackrule.DOCX";
var asb = @"C:\Users\dheale\Desktop\Word Docs\TESTING\asb.DOCX";
var outDoc = @"C:\Users\dheale\Desktop\Word Docs\TESTING\out.DOCX";

var sources = new List<Source>
{
    new Source(new WmlDocument(asb), 0, 80, false),
    new Source(new WmlDocument(letterhead), true),
    new Source(new WmlDocument(asb), 80,120, false),
    new Source(new WmlDocument(blackrule), true),
    new Source(new WmlDocument(asb), 200, false),
    new Source(new WmlDocument(letterhead), true)
};

var doc = DocumentBuilder.BuildDocument(sources);
```

My issue is trying to figure out what the paragraph index is. The original document has tags to identify where the template should be placed.

Currently to get the ID I’m doing the following:

```
var ParagraphIndex = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.ChildElements
    .Where(w => w.XmlQualifiedName.Name == "p").ToList()
    .FindIndex(f => f.InnerXml.Contains(templateTag));
```

However, the longer the document, the more off this index is.

Is there a better and more accurate way of getting the indexes of the paragraphs?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution for this? I'm running into the exact same issue.
It seems like when iterating through paragraphs, every table cell is a paragraph, but that isn't what the DocumentBuilder is expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you get Paragraph with the tag, then insert your content after it?

```
var searchedParagraph = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.ChildElements
    .Where(w => w.XmlQualifiedName.Name == "p")
    .FirstOrDefault(f => f.InnerXml.Contains(templateTag));
if (searchedParagraph != null) {
   OpenXmlElement parent = searchedParagraph.Parent;
   //Add Code here to create your paragraphWithContent
   ....
   //End paragraphWithContent 

   parent.InsertAfter(paragraphWithContent, searchedParagraph);
}
```

Something like this.

Comment: The issue with inserting the content is it loses images contained within the headers. The content has a lot of complex data in it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is exactly the problem you're running into, but I was trying to do something very similar (detecting paragraphs in a Word doc that consist of a certain tag and replacing them with new sections) and ran into a very similar problem.

What seems to have worked for me is iterating through all the elements of the body whether they be paragraphs or not. For each element, increment the counter by 1 to keep track of where we are in the document. If we are in a paragraph, check for the tag in replace the paragraph with its own section (in my case, using Open XML Power Tools `DocumentBuilder`.)

Pseudocode:

```
foreach (var element in templateWpd.MainDocumentPart.RootElement.Elements<Body>().Single().Elements())
{
    if (element is Paragraph p && p.InnerText == "MyTagToReplace")
    {
        if (withinSource)
        {
            var count = currentSourceEnd - currentSourceStart + 1;
            sources.Add(new Source(templateWml, currentSourceStart, count, true));
            withinSource = false;
        }

        sources.Add(new Source(targetProse));
    }        
    else
    {
        if (withinSource)
        {
            currentSourceEnd = i;
        }
        else
        {
            withinSource = true;
            currentSourceStart = i;
            currentSourceEnd = i;
        }
    }

    i++;
}

if (withinSource)
{
    sources.Add(new Source(templateWml, currentSourceStart, true));
    withinSource = false;
}
```

Comment: I'm no longer working with word docs, but I'm glad you found something that works for you!